# System.AccessViolationException when iterating through a pointer inside clr.dll library of .NET 4.0 on Windows 10 specifically

Tags: c#, clr, extern

This code is from another file which worked on some older version of windows. When compiling I get System.AccessViolationException after some iterations instead giving me the pointer.

```cs
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr lib, string proc);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lib);

    void Main(){
    ptr = (byte*)GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("clr.dll"), "_CorExeMain").ToPointer();
        while (((((ptr[0] != 0xe8) || (*((ptr - 3)) != 0x89)) || ((*((ptr - 2)) != 0x45) || (*((ptr - 1)) != 0xfc))) || ((ptr[5] != 0xc7) || ((ptr + 5)[1] != 0x45))) || ((ptr + 5)[2] != 0xfc))
        {
            ptr++;
        }
     }
```

What do I miss here? 
Thanks.

Comment: It tells you that pointers are unsafe.  And that error checking is not optional when you pinvoke OS functions.

Comment: Do I need the virtualprotect attribute to r/w?